# Search API is limited to the last 7 days?

Tags: twitter

Tried, after auth, to call:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23archimedecreativa&src=hash
```

If I do it directly on Twitter :

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23archimedecreativa&src=hash
```

I get more than 6 results. Why with api only 6 result? (which are in the last 7 days).

I can't get all tweets with that Hashtag through api at the moment? I'm afraid reading [this](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/3619)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their API documentation states it is limited to 6-9 days.

Comment: That's terrible! Why are you limiting those operations in your opinion?

Comment: They limit them to lower bandwidth.  Some People post say 20 times a day.  That would return a minimum of 120 results.

Comment: It's a social network, informations must be available anywhere/everytime. It's a big company, they should invest in his technology, not limit them. I repeat: terrible approch...